# Two SSD in Thinkpad W520 and Internal RAID - Not Enabled

Tags: dual-boot, raid, thinkpad, lenovo, ssd

Looking for some suggestions: I have bought a Lenovo Thinkpad W520 with a SSD of 160 GB. windows 7 came as a default OS. My Storage subsystem has "Internal RAID Not Enabled". I want to replace my optical drive bay by a 2nd SSD of 180 GB where I would like to install Ubuntu so that I can dual boot Linux and windows. My questions are, can I do this with this configuration? What does "internal raid" mean? Is it true that "Internal RAID Not Enabled" will not allow me to use 2nd SSD as a system drive?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Leave RAID to Linux when you need it, don't enable it in your BIOS. You don't need RAID to use your second drive, it is just a mechanism to make your two drives appear as if it is one larger drive (or a mirrored one). For most consumer grade motherboard based RAID implementations, the Linux implementation is superior. In Linux RAID is supplied by [`md`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm) (metadevice). Check [RAID on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) for more information.

Comment: I believe `metadevice` is the name used in Oracle/Sun Solaris, for Linux it appears to be derived from `multiple device`. What's in a name.